# WCF Trace and Performance

Tags: wcf, performance

I just wonder is there is sensible explanaition to such an issue:

- I have turned on trace on WCF Console host. When I analyze that trace, I can see that individual activities duration is maximum 4 seconds
- On client application I have made simple duration mesurement (before and after call to WCF service). Here results are much bigger (up to 20seconds).

I wonder what is happening in 20-4 seconds? Maybe time traced by host in only time of processing user code, and the rest of time is spent on encoding/decoding messages?

Test is performed in LAN.

Thanks Pawel

P.S. My first thought was that durations on client & server would be comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Does one call from the client trigger several individual activities on the server (4x5=20)

Other thing to check is that you are logging in the correct place.

Are you using any streaming or async that could cause this?

Even if you had a routing problem that set it to the internet and back you would not expect that large difference.